# can't update CocoaPods in flutter terminal from android studio

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

**This is the full error message**

```
Warning: CocoaPods minimum required version 1.9.0 or greater not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

any command which I can directly from the Android studio terminal to update CocoaPods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally after waisting my whole day.
we can't update CocoaPods from very old version to new version so.
1 - sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2-sudo gem install cocoapods:1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with this command

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Try to without home brew

```
1 - sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

2 - sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin

3 - cocoapods pod install
```

Comment: for that we need to install home-brew. I didn't want to go that way.

Comment: try the above solution without homebrew.

Comment: the 2nd point you have mentioned, is unclear, and does not specify anything to install.

Comment: Write to install cocoapods - gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
got this error now

Comment: Try to change permission. 

cd /var/lib
|
sudo chmod -R a+w gems/

Comment: chmod: gems: No such file or directory

Comment: I had a similar problem and was only able to solve using brew

Comment: You need to install brew - brew install cocoapods